# User input with Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext, eoferror

Is it possible to test accepting user input with Sublime Text 2? For instance, this:

```
x = input()
print(x)
```

Spits out an EOFError. How can I have it accept user input? Or open a console window to accept user input?

Answer (score 3):

Try this plugin, SublimeREPL provides a simple python console:

https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL